# File not found main.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, environment-variables

I have QT installed in my PC, which is using the Visual Studio 2010 compiler

[image]

I tested this with a simple hello world application, and it works fine.

However now I am trying to use OpenCV with QT. I have installed Visual Studio 2010 express and professional both, and opencv works fine there. But, when I try to run the OpenCV in QT, I get the following error

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main

    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
    
    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
    
    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
    
    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
    
    release\FirstProject.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

Following is my *FirstProject.pro* file's content

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-26T11:15:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = FirstProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include\
LIBS += -LC:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib \
-lopencv_calib3d240d.lib\
-lopencv_contrib240d.lib\
-lopencv_core240d.lib\
-lopencv_features2d240d.lib\
-lopencv_flann240d.lib\
-lopencv_gpu240d.lib\
-lopencv_haartraining_engined.lib\
-lopencv_highgui240d.lib\
-lopencv_imgproc240d.lib\
-lopencv_legacy240d.lib\
-lopencv_ml240d.lib\
-lopencv_nonfree240d.lib\
-lopencv_objdetect240d.lib\
-lopencv_photo240d.lib\
-lopencv_stitching240d.lib\
-lopencv_ts240d.lib\
-lopencv_video240d.lib\
-lopencv_videostab240d.lib
```

I tried by chainging to the following FirstProject.pro content, but no good at all

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-26T11:15:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = FirstProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include\
LIBS += -LC:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib \
-lopencv_core240 \
-lopencv_highgui240 \
-lopencv_imgproc240 \
-lopencv_features2d240 \
-lopencv_calib3d240
```

Following is my code

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat image = imread("D:/Tulips.jpg");

    if(!image.data)
    {
        cout << "Error loading image" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        namedWindow("Image");
        imshow("Image",image);
    }

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The only way to remove the issue is adding the libs one by one, with the complete path

```
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_calib3d240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_contrib240.lib
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you hold `CTRL` and hover over a library name, the ones which Qt has detected successfully will cause the mouse to turn into a hand icon

Answer (score 2):

QT Project files try to handle file/directory separators uniformly, ie, forward v's back slashes.  It shouldn't matter which is used.  However, maybe there's some translation going on.

Try replacing all backslashes '\' with forward versions '/'.  Qmake will convert them appropriately.

Replace with `-LC:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib`

It also might be the final backslash on your INCLUDEPATH that's the problem.  Maybe it's joining up next line?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I have to convert all the "\" at the end of every library include line as well?

Comment: the "\" at the end of every include line is to tell the qmake that the current include is not yet end. if you remove it, you will have to do something like "LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib LIBS += -lopencv_core240 LIBS += ..."

Comment: To paraphrase YamHon.CHAN, yes, you do need the backslash for each LIBS line, to continue the line.  However the INCLUDEPATH line doesn't need it because you're not continuing the line, and trailing slashes (back or forward) on a directory is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I found the answer nowhere. after 8 days trying to fix it finally I found the answer and I want to share it with u.

when u use static linking opencv first check if your libraries are really static linked , to do so open a developer command prompt msvc , navigate into your libraries path , and type the command bellow :

```
lib /LIBS opencv_world.lib
```

rather than opencv_world.lib you can put any other library names.

then check there were only refrenced .obj files in it , so that means u can use this library static.
then remember when u use static lib in opencv , u need to at some other libraries to ur project that in dynamic linking u didnt need to. these libraries are in your library directory that their name doesnt start with opencv.
u can see some of them bellow :

```
IlmImf.lib
ippicvmt.lib
ippiw.lib
ittnotify.lib
libjasper.lib
libtiff.lib
libwebp.lib
zlib.lib
```

remeber , If u got the error "couldnt find library" , use the exact path to add it. for example :

```
LIBS += E:\opencv\build-x86-static\install\x86\vc15\staticlib\zlib.lib
```